# What is phrase or idiom for the one who bells the cat is the only one who gets killed

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What is phrase or idiom for the one who bells the cat is the only one who gets killed. Usually in company workhorses are the one who are overloaded with work because along with their capacity to work hard they equally are honest and therefore bound to react in situation which concerned them and not remain bystanders. They are thus bound to get into trouble too for taking the initiative.

Comment: What does *bells the cat* mean and in which dialect(s) of English is it used?

Comment: @Clare [Here's a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belling_the_cat) that discusses the expression and its origins.

Comment: **bell the cat**:take the danger of a shared enterprise upon oneself.[https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bell_the_cat]

Answer (score 1):

> - **[sow the wind, reap the whirlwind](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sow_the_wind,_reap_the_whirlwind)**  often shortened to **reap the whirl wind**
>
> *Every decision has consequences; a person's actions will come back to him*.
>
> Synonyms:
>
> - *what goes around comes around*
> - *reap what one sows*
>
> *A person's actions, whether good or bad, will often have consequences for that person.*
>
> ([en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what_goes_around_comes_around#English))

Comment: *Reap the whirl-wind* is about as close as you could get and yet, *belling the cat* in my experience always refers only to the act and never to any reaction, however malign.

Comment: If there is no other alternative, then "sow the wind, reap the whirlwind" is as close as it can get. however there is that situation where you sow the wind which sound evil already. I rather say "sow a good seed and even then reap a whirl wind" kind of situation as one is doing something good and still reaping bad result.